# Repeat section of texture over mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm using a spritesheet (atlas) for low res textures, I want to able to repeat the same portion of the texture multipĺe times without adding more triangles.
I coded so far a plane like this:

```
var textureSpritemap = loadTexture('textures.png');
var geometry = new t3.PlaneGeometry(80, 80);
var material = new t3.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureSpritemap});
var plane = new t3.Mesh(geometry, material);
setPlaneUVs(plane, [0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0]);
textureSpritemap.repeat.set(2, 2);
```

I understand that it's possible to repeat a texture multiple times, but I want to be able to repeat only a portion.

Sprite map:

### [image]

Intended result:

### [image]

Actual result:

### [image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: [oh hey](http://0fps.net/2013/07/09/texture-atlases-wrapping-and-mip-mapping/)

Comment: Have a look at http://threejs.org/examples/misc_ubiquity_test2.html